# Sum values per key from csv file

Tags: python, python-2.7

The code I have below is importing an excel csv file (amusement ride accidents) and I took two of the columns I needed - state and the number of people injured. Then I used append to condense the state, but couldn't do that with numbered injured. I need to add the number injured per state from my dictionary I created. Nothing I have looked up works. I was trying to use a for loop to iterate through my new dictionary and total the sum per state(there's about 38 in this dictionary). Any suggestions are much appreciated. This is a beginner class using python 2.7

```py
import csv

source = open('Saferparks-dataset-2017.csv')

amusement = csv.reader(source)

ride_accidents_state = {}

next(amusement)

for col in amusement:

    if col[2] in ride_accidents_state:

        ride_accidents_state[col[2]].append(col[12]) 

    else:

        ride_accidents_state[col[2]] = [col[12]]

print ride_accidents_state
```

Comment: It might be helpful to provide some example output from running your code, particularly the output of the "print ride_accidents_state" statement, otherwise the reviewers won't have much to go on to recommend a solution.  BTW:  As I'm sure you know, Python 2.7 is going to be end-of-life in a couple months, so starting to learn fresh with Python 3.X might be a good thing to do if possible.  I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, yes we are actually starting JS after this project is done next week.This is a snippet from my dictionary when I print. I need to total the values. {'WA': ['1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '3', '1', '6', '1', '2', '3'], 'WI': ['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '2', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '2', '1', '1', '1', '2', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '4', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '2', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '3', '1', '1', '1', '1'],

Answer (score 0):

You might consider simplifying things by doing the summing immediately in your "for loop" instead of doing appends and then having to sum over that list.  Here is an example that shows the approach using a similar structure to what you have.  I hope this helps:

```
myData = [['WA', '1'], ['WA', '2'], ['WI', '4'], ['WI', '3'], ['WA', '10']]
ride_accidents_state = {}

for col in myData:

    if col[0] in ride_accidents_state:

        ride_accidents_state[col[0]] = ride_accidents_state[col[0]] + int(col[1])

    else:

        ride_accidents_state[col[0]] = int(col[1])

print ride_accidents_state
```

Comment: The csv file is big and set up with each amusement ride accident by date for 7 years. So there's a bunch of columns I don't want. Then I need to condense the incidents by each state, use that as the key and then take each number injured by state and sum them. If I sum it before hand it will take a long time, so I was hoping I could do it in a for loop, if that makes sense? Thank you for helping me!